# Reading data from a TCP Socket not getting all of the data

Tags: c#, android, sockets, tcp

I am working on a C# and android client/server application.

Android is sending a message to C# and I can see it is sending the correct data, however C# doesn't receive all of it.

Below is the code I have in C#

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, serverTCPPort);
                tcpListener.Start();

                while (true)
                {
                    tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                    stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                    reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                    writer.NewLine = "\r\n";
                    writer.AutoFlush = true;
                    byte[] serverData = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    int length = stream.Read(serverData, 0, serverData.Length);
                    string received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(serverData, 0, length);
}
```

Below is how I am sending the data via Android

i

```
f (contactInformation.photoBase64String != null) {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(contactInformation.photoBase64String));

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                bitmap64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming call from " + contactInformation.contactName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            XmlSettings xmlSettings = new XmlSettings();
            xmlSettings.setIndent(true);
            XmlWriter xmlWriter = new XmlWriter(xmlSettings);

            xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();
            xmlWriter.writeStartElement("StatusManager");
            xmlWriter.writeElementString("Command", Defines.ServerCommands.IncomingCall.toString());
            xmlWriter.writeStartElement("CallInformation");
            xmlWriter.writeElementString("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            xmlWriter.writeElementString("ContactName", contactInformation.contactName);
            if (contactInformation.photoBase64String != null)
            {
                xmlWriter.writeElementString("PhotoUri", bitmap64Encoded);
            }
            xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
            xmlWriter.writeEndElement();

            String xml = xmlWriter.returnXmlOutput();

            TCPSender tcpSender = new TCPSender(context, DeviceManagement.servers.get(0), xmlWriter.returnXmlOutput());
            Thread thread = new Thread(tcpSender);
            thread.start();
```

The TCP Sender is

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("TCPSender", xml);
        HelperClass helperClass = new HelperClass();
        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(foundServerInformation.ipAddress, foundServerInformation.tcpServerPort);
            
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
            output.println(xml);
            output.flush();
```

I guess the data is too big for the byte array but I can't find a way of how to ensure I get all of the information that Android is sending.

Comment: I'm no expert but just out of curiosity, what data are you sending and how are you sending it from Android?

Comment: @SamRad TCP sockets are pretty standard, I don't see why using them to send data between an Android device and (presumably) a Windows desktop would be too difficult. Google has decent documentation on them.

Comment: Yeah :) but I was about to help because I did the same thing with Python at the desktop side and Android on the other via Bluetooth. Just wanted to see if I can help.

Comment: `tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize` makes me raise an eyebrow.  I would expect you would want to create a byte[] the size of what the client is sending your listener.  So would you want to use `tcpClient.SendBufferSize`?

Comment: @Boardy How large is the data your trying to receive? The default 'TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize' is 8192. If you want more than that, you'll need to explicitly set the desired size. See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivebuffersize.aspx)

Comment: Is it only receiving the **END** of the data??? My educated guess. You are instantiating a new serverData array each iteration. It will overwrite any previous data. What are you doing with Received and when are you ever breaking out of the loop?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will look into them later on, at work currently, regarding what I do with the received data, there is actually more code it goes off to other functions but it wasn't relevant so didn't include. The while loop stays running forever waiting for new messages. I do get the beginning of the received message but its the end that is chopped off

Comment: I've updated my question to include how I am sending the data, I've tied using TcpClient.SendBufferSize instead of ReceiveBufferSize but doesn't seem to make much difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to get it working, it was something to do with using the SendReceiveBuffer which I did try but didn't work but now it does so I guess I missed something.

Below is the code I am using to receive all of the data

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, serverTCPPort);
                tcpListener.Start();
                string received = "";
                while (true)
                {
                    tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                    stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                    reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                    writer.NewLine = "\r\n";
                    writer.AutoFlush = true;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpClient.SendBufferSize];
                    int recv = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        recv = stream.Read(bytes, 0, tcpClient.SendBufferSize);
                        received += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, recv);

                        if (received.EndsWith("\n\n"))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to know where the problem might be (I see your code is OK), but here you have a working example from Microsoft how it should be done, maybe it gives you some clues.

```
TcpListener server=null;   
try
{
      // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
      Int32 port = 13000;
      IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
      // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
      server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

      // Start listening for client requests.
      server.Start();

      // Buffer for reading data
      Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
      String data = null;

      // Enter the listening loop.
      while(true) 
      {
        Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
        // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

        data = null;

        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        int i;

        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
        while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
        {   
          // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
          data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
          Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

          // Process the data sent by the client.
          data = data.ToUpper();

          byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

          // Send back a response.
          stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
          Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);            
        }

        // Shutdown and end connection
        client.Close();
      }
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
    }
    finally
    {
       // Stop listening for new clients.
       server.Stop();
    }


    Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
    Console.Read();
```